# Binaryreader in 2 threads and infinite loop c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, binaryreader

I am writting client-server communicator.
Now I reached the point where I don't know what to do. So...

In my Client I have 2 threads. 
In those 2 threads I am using this same BinaryReader- in one thread for example when adding new contact  and in second thread in infinite loop (waiting for new message from server).

When I am adding contact, my application is not working properly because BinaryReaders in separated threads are reading reply alternately.

I realized that I have to use mutex.

Here is my code of client.class:

Adding contact:

```
      bw.Write((int)Codes.AddContact);
        bw.Write(login);
        mutex.WaitOne();
        int ans = br.ReadInt32(); // waiting for 'ok'
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

Second thread (infinite loop):

```
            while (logged)
                {
                    mutex.WaitOne();
                    var action = (Codes)br.ReadInt32(); //stucks here
                    dp.Handle(action, bw, br);// dispatcher
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

                }
```

And my problem now is that this line:

```
  var action = (Codes)br.ReadInt32();
```

is waiting infinitly for some message form the server, mutex is in waiting-state so when I am trying to add a new contact, my client freezes here:

```
  mutex.WaitOne();
```

Is there any way to interrupt this reading or maybe do you know better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you flushing your writes? Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, always after write.

Comment: A mutex cannot solve this problem.  You will need some kind of higher level protocol that helps you decide which particular thread should be the one that handles a specific message.  So you can have one thread doing the reading and a set of thread-safe queues to distribute them.  Pretty easy to over-engineer this btw, "message bus" and "pub/sub pattern" are middleware buzzwords.